# Shuffle pictures randomly, open link in new tab

Tags: php, tabs, shuffle

I have following code that shuffle pictures randomly. What should i add to open every link in new tab? I tried with target="_blank" but it didnt work.

thanks in advance

```
<?php
define('LINK_URL', 0);
define('IMAGE_URL', 1);
$images = array(

   array(LINK_URL => 'http://www.linktosmth1.com', IMAGE_URL => '/pics/sponsors/1.jpg'),
   array(LINK_URL => 'http://www.linktosmth2.com', IMAGE_URL => '/pics/sponsors/2.jpg'),
   array(LINK_URL => 'http://www.linktosmth3.com', IMAGE_URL => '/pics/sponsors/3.jpg'),

);
shuffle($images);

foreach($images as $image) {
   echo '<a href="' . $image[LINK_URL] . '"><img src="' . $image[IMAGE_URL] . '" /></a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="' . $image[LINK_URL] . '"target="_blank"><img src="' . $image[IMAGE_URL] . '" /></a>'
```

This should work as this is normal HTML.